# Relation between $SU(4)$ and $SO(6)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

This is more of a particle physics question than maths. Since $\operatorname{SO}(6)$ and $\operatorname{SU}(4)$ are isomorphic, how are the fields (say for example scalar fields of ${\mathcal{N}}=4$ Super Yang Mills in $4d$) transforming under **6** dimensional vector representation of $\operatorname{SO}(6)$ related to the fields transforming under antisymmetric **6** of $\operatorname{SU}(4)$?

Answer (score 23):

I) An *existence* proof that $SU(4)\cong SPIN(6)$ is e.g. given in the lectures [PG course on Spin Geometry](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/) taught by José Figueroa-O'Farrill, see Lemma 8.1 in the lecture named *Parallel and Killing spinors*. In this answer we will concentrate on the *explicit* realization of such Lie group isomorphism, which OP may find useful to his question about the corresponding Lie algebra representation theory.

II)

> $SL(4;\mathbb{C})$ is (the double cover of) the special [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) $SO(6;\mathbb{C})$.

This follows partly because:

1. There is a bijective isometry from the $6$-dimensional complex vector space $(\mathbb{C}^6,||\cdot||^2)$
   $$\begin{align} \vec{v}~=~&(x^1,x^2,x^3,y^1,y^2,y^3), \cr
    x^a,y^a~\in~& \mathbb{C},\qquad a~\in~ \{1,2,3\}, \end{align}\tag{1} $$
   endowed with the standard bilinear (as opposed to sesquilinear) form
   $$\begin{align} ||\vec{v}||^2~:=~& \sum_{a,b=1}^3 x^a \eta_{ab} x^b +  \sum_{a=1}^3 y^a \eta_{ab} y^b,  \cr
   \eta_{ab}~=~&{\rm diag}(+1,+1,+1), \end{align}\tag{2} $$
   and the space $(so(4;\mathbb{C}),{\rm Pf}(\cdot))$ of antisymmetric complex $4\times 4$ matrices,
   $$\mathbb{C}^6 ~\cong ~ so(4;\mathbb{C})
   ~:=~\{A\in {\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C}) \mid A^{t}=-A\}, \tag{3}$$
   endowed with the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian)
   $$\begin{align} {\rm Pf}(A)~=~&\frac{1}{8}\sum_{\mu,\nu,\lambda,\sigma=1}^4\epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}A^{\mu\nu} A^{\lambda\sigma}\cr
   ~=~&A^{12}A^{34} + A^{31}A^{24} + A^{23}A^{14}~=~||\vec{v}||^2, \cr 
    \epsilon_{1234}~=~&1,\end{align} \tag{4}$$
   if we identify

$$\begin{align} A^{ab}~=~&\sum_{c=1}^3\epsilon^{abc} (x_c-iy_c)\qquad \Leftrightarrow\qquad 
x_a-iy_a ~=~\frac{1}{2}\sum_{b,c=1}^3\epsilon_{abc}A^{bc} ,\cr \epsilon^{123}~=~&1~=~\epsilon_{123},\qquad A^{a4}~=~ x^a+iy^a, \qquad a,b,c\in \{1,2,3\}, \cr
A~=~&\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
0& x_3-iy_3 &-x_2+iy_2 & x^1+iy^1  \cr  
 -x_3+iy_3 &0&x_1-iy_1 & x^2+iy^2  \cr 
x_2-iy_2 &-x_1+iy_1 & 0& x^3+iy^3 \cr  
-x^1-iy^1&-x^2-iy^2&-x^3-iy^3&0\end{array} \right].\end{align}\tag{5} $$
We stress again that the bilinear form (2) has indefinite signature because $x^a,y^b \in \mathbb{C}$ are in general complex numbers.

2. There is a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $\rho: SL(4;\mathbb{C})\times  so(4;\mathbb{C}) \to  so(4;\mathbb{C})$ given by
   $$\begin{align} g\quad \mapsto&\quad\rho(g)A~:= ~gA g^{t},
   \cr 
   g~\in~& SL(4;\mathbb{C})\subseteq {\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C}),\cr
   A~\in~& so(4;\mathbb{C})\subseteq {\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C}),\end{align}\tag{6}  $$
   which is length preserving
   $$\begin{align} {\rm Pf}(\rho(g)A)~=~&{\rm Pf}(gAg^t)\cr
   ~=~&\det(g){\rm Pf}(A)\cr
   ~=~&{\rm Pf}(A),\end{align}\tag{7}$$
   i.e. $g$ is an orthogonal transformation. In other words, there is a [Lie group homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_homomorphism)
   $$\begin{align}\rho: SL(4;\mathbb{C}) \quad\to&\quad O(so(4;\mathbb{C});\mathbb{C})~\cong~ O(6;\mathbb{C}) , \cr
   \rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{4 \times 4})~=~&{\bf 1}_{so(4;\mathbb{C})}.\end{align}\tag{8}$$

III)

> $Sp(4;\mathbb{C})$ is (the double cover of) the special orthogonal group $SO(5;\mathbb{C})$.

This follows partly because:

1. The [symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group)
   $$\begin{align}Sp(4;\mathbb{F})~:=~&\left\{ 
   M\in{\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{F}) \left| M^t\Omega M =\Omega  \right. \right\}, \cr
   \Omega~:=~& \begin{pmatrix} {\bf 0} & {\bf 1}_{2\times 2} \cr   -{\bf 1}_{2\times 2} &{\bf 0}\end{pmatrix}.\end{align} \tag{9}$$
   is a subgroup of $SL(4;\mathbb{F})$, cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/242091/11127) Math.SE post.
2. The subspace
   $$V~:=~\left\{A\in so(4;\mathbb{C}) \left|  {\rm tr}(\Omega A)~=~0 \right. \right\}~\cong~\mathbb{C}^5, \tag{10} $$
   (which corresponds to $y^2=0$) is invariant under the group action $\rho$ restricted to the symplectic group $Sp(4;\mathbb{C})$.
3. In other words, there is a Lie group homomorphism
   $$\begin{align}\rho: Sp(4;\mathbb{C}) \quad\to&\quad O(V;\mathbb{C})~\cong~ O(5;\mathbb{C}) , \cr
   \rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{4 \times 4})~=~&{\bf 1}_V.\end{align}\tag{11}$$

IV)

> $SL(4;\mathbb{R})$ is (the double cover of) the restricted [split orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $SO^+(3,3;\mathbb{R})$.

This follows partly from Section II by restricting the coordinates $x^a\in\mathbb{R}$ to real numbers; the coordinates $y^a\in i\mathbb{R}$ to imaginary numbers; and the matrices $A$  in eq. (3) to real matrices
$$\mathbb{R}^{3,3} ~\cong ~ so(4;\mathbb{R})
~:=~\{A\in {\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R}) \mid A^{t}=-A\}. \tag{12}$$
In other words, there is a Lie group homomorphism
$$\begin{align}\rho: SL(4;\mathbb{R}) \quad\to&\quad O(so(4;\mathbb{R}) ;\mathbb{R})~\cong~ O(3,3;\mathbb{R}) , \cr
\rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{4 \times 4})~=~&{\bf 1}_{so(4;\mathbb{R})}.\end{align}\tag{13}$$

V)

> $Sp(4;\mathbb{R})$ is (the double cover of) the [restricted anti de Sitter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $SO^+(3,2;\mathbb{R})$.

This follows partly because:

1. The subspace
   $$V~:=~\left\{A\in so(4;\mathbb{R}) \left|  {\rm tr}(\Omega A)~=~0 \right. \right\}~\cong~\mathbb{R}^{3,2}, \tag{14} $$
   (which corresponds to $y^2=0$) is invariant under the group action $\rho$ restricted to the symplectic group $Sp(4;\mathbb{R})$.
2. In other words, there is a Lie group homomorphism
   $$\begin{align}\rho: Sp(4;\mathbb{R}) \quad\to&\quad O(V;\mathbb{R})~\cong~ O(3,2;\mathbb{R}) , \cr
   \rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{4 \times 4})~=~&{\bf 1}_V.\end{align}\tag{15}$$

VI) Let us now address OP's question (v3).

> $SU(4)$ is (the double cover of) the special orthogonal group $SO(6;\mathbb{R})$.

This follows partly because:

1. The complex $6$-dimensional vector space
   $$\begin{align} {\rm Re}(\mathbb{C}^6)\oplus_{\mathbb{R}} {\rm Im}(\mathbb{C}^6)~=~& \mathbb{C}^6~\cong~so(4;\mathbb{C})\cr
   ~=~&so^{-}(4;\mathbb{C}) \oplus_{\mathbb{R}} so^{+}(4;\mathbb{C})\end{align}\tag{16}$$
   splits in two real $6$-dimensional subspaces 6
   $$\left.\begin{array}{c} {\rm Im}(\mathbb{C}^6) \cr {\rm Re}(\mathbb{C}^6) \end{array}  \right\}~\cong~so^{\pm}(4;\mathbb{C})~:=~ \{ A\in so(4;\mathbb{C}) \mid \star A = \pm A^{\dagger} \} \tag{17} $$
   via a selfdual/antiselfdual-type condition. Here the [Hodge-dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) is defined as
   $$\begin{align} (\star A)^{\mu\nu}~:=~& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\lambda,\sigma=1}^4\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma} A_{\lambda\sigma},  \cr  
   A_{\lambda\sigma}~:=~&\sum_{\mu,\nu=1}^4 \eta_{\lambda\mu}A^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\nu\sigma},\cr 
   \mu,\nu,\lambda,\sigma~\in~& \{1,2,3,4\} , \cr
   \epsilon^{1234}~=~&1,\end{align}\tag{18} $$
   where
   $$\eta_{\mu\nu}~=~{\rm diag}(+1,+1,+1,+1) \tag{19} $$
   is the standard bilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^4$ to raise and lower indices. The Hodge-dual is an involution
   $$ \star^2~=~ \det (\eta_{\mu\nu})~=~ 1. \tag{20}$$
   We have
   $$\begin{align} (\star A)^{ab}~=~&\sum_{c=1}^3\epsilon^{abc} A_{c4} , \cr 
   (\star A)^{a4}~=~& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{b,c=1}^3\epsilon^{abc} A_{bc}, \cr a,b,c~\in~& \{1,2,3\}, \cr \epsilon^{123}~=~&1.\end{align}\tag{21}$$
2. Hence there is a bijective isometry between the positive definite, real $6$-dimensional, Euclidean vector space $({\rm Re}(\mathbb{C}^6),||\cdot||^2)$, and the space $(so^{-}(4;\mathbb{C}),{\rm Pf}(\cdot))$ of "antiselfdual" $4\times 4$ matrices, where
   $$ 4 {\rm Pf}(A)~\stackrel{(4)+(18)}{=}~
   \sum_{\mu,\nu=1}^4 A^{\mu\nu} (\star A)_{\mu\nu}
   ~\stackrel{(17)}{=}~\sum_{\mu,\nu=1}^4 A^{\mu\nu} \bar{A}_{\mu\nu}~\geq~0. \tag{22}$$
3. The Lie group
   $$\begin{align} SU(4)~:=~&\{ g \in {\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C}) \mid g^{\dagger}\eta g = \eta \wedge \det(g) = 1 \} \cr
   ~\subseteq~& SL(4;\mathbb{C})~\subseteq~{\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C}) \end{align} \tag{23} $$
   is a subgroup of $SL(4;\mathbb{C})$. Hence we can consider the restriction of the group action $\rho: SL(4;\mathbb{C})\times  so(4;\mathbb{C}) \to  so(4;\mathbb{C})$ to just $SU(4)$.
4. The two subspaces $so^{\pm}(4;\mathbb{C})$ are invariant under the (restricted) group action $\rho: SU(4)\times  so(4;\mathbb{C}) \to  so(4;\mathbb{C})$,
   $$\begin{align} \star (\rho(g)A) ~=~&\pm (\rho(g)A)^{\dagger}, \cr
   g~\in~& SU(4),\cr 
   A~\in~& so^{\pm}(4;\mathbb{C}).\end{align}\tag{24} $$
5. In conclusion, there is a Lie group homomorphism
   $$\begin{align}\rho: SU(4) \quad\to&\quad O(so^{-}(4;\mathbb{C}) ;\mathbb{R})~\cong~ O({\rm Re}(\mathbb{C}^6) ;\mathbb{R})~\cong~ O(6;\mathbb{R}) , \cr
   \rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{4 \times 4})~=~&{\bf 1}_{so^{-}(4;\mathbb{C})}.\end{align}\tag{25}$$

VII)

> $SU(2,2)$ is (the double cover of) the Lie group $SO^+(2,4;\mathbb{R})$.

This follows partly from Section IV by changing the signatures of the bilinear form
$$\begin{align}   \eta_{ab}~=~&{\rm diag}(-1,-1,+1), \cr
\eta_{\mu\nu}~=~&{\rm diag}(-1,-1,+1,+1).\end{align}\tag{26} $$

VIII) Since this post is about (local) isomorphisms of 15-dimensional [simple Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_simple_Lie_groups), let us for completeness mention the following.

> $SL(2;\mathbb{H})$ is (the double cover of) the restricted [Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $SO^+(1,5;\mathbb{R})$.

This follows partly because:

1. There is a star algebra monomorphism
   $\Phi:\mathbb{H}\to {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ given by
   $$\begin{align}\mathbb{H}~\ni~ q~=~&q^0+iq^3 +jq^2+kq^1
   ~=~\alpha +\beta j \cr 
   ~~\stackrel{\Phi}{\mapsto}~~& \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \cr -\bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha} \end{pmatrix} ~=~ q^0{\bf 1}_{2\times 2}+i\sum_{a=1}^3 q^a \sigma_a~\in~ {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}),\cr 
   \alpha~\equiv~& q^0+iq^3~\in~\mathbb{C}, \qquad \beta~\equiv~ q^2+iq^1~\in~\mathbb{C},\end{align}\tag{27}$$
   Define an involution $(\cdot)^t: \mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ as
   $$\begin{align}q^t~:=~&q|_{q^2\to-q^2}~:=~q^0+iq^3 -jq^2+kq^1~=~ -j\bar{q}j, \cr q~\in~&\mathbb{H},\end{align}\tag{28}$$
   which we will call the "transposed" quaternion.
   Note that
   $$\begin{align} \Phi(q)^{\dagger}~=~\Phi(\bar{q})
   \quad\text{and}&\quad
   \Phi(q)^t~=~\Phi(q^t), \cr 
   q~\in~\mathbb{H}. \end{align}\tag{29}$$
2. The star algebra monomorphism (27) is extended in the natural way to a star algebra monomorphism
   $\Phi:{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H})\to {\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$
   (which we also call $\Phi$) such that
   $$\begin{align} \Phi(m)^{\dagger}~=~\Phi(m^{\dagger})\quad\text{and}&\quad
   \Phi(m)^t~=~\Phi(m^t),  \cr
   m~\in~&{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}). \end{align}\tag{30}$$
3. There is no canonical notion of a [quaternionic determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_matrix#Determinants), so we define the special linear group of quaternionic $2\times 2$ matrices as
   $$SL(2;\mathbb{H})~:=~\Phi^{-1}(SL(4;\mathbb{C})). \tag{31}$$
4. The set of "antisymmetric" quaternionic $2\times 2$ matrices is
   $$\begin{align}so(2;\mathbb{H})~:=~&\left\{ m\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \mid m^t=-m \right\}\cr
   ~=~&\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} rj & -q^t \cr q & sj \end{pmatrix} \in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \mid r,s\in\mathbb{R}, ~q\in\mathbb{H} \right\}\cr
   ~=~&\Phi^{-1}(so(4;\mathbb{C})), \end{align}\tag{32} $$
   cf. the above definition (28) of "transposed" quaternion.
5. Comparing with the bilinear form (2) from Section II, we identify one real variable
   $$ x^3~=~\frac{r+s}{2}~\in~\mathbb{R} \tag{33} $$
   and five imaginary variables
   $$\begin{align} y^3~=~& \frac{i(r-s)}{2},\cr  
   x^1~=~&-iq^1,\cr  
   y^1~=~&-iq^2,\cr  
   x^2~=~&iq^3,\cr  
   y^2~=~&iq^0,\end{align} \tag{34} $$
   In other words, the bilinear form (2) restricts to
   $$\begin{align} ||\vec{v}||^2~=~& rs-|q|^2,\cr
   r,s~\in~&\mathbb{R},  \cr
   q~\in~&\mathbb{H} ,\end{align}\tag{35} $$
   with signature (1,5).

References:

1. Paul Garrett, [*Sporadic isogenies to orthogonal groups,*](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf) 2015.

Answer (score 8):

Physicists use dimension to denote representations of particular simple Lie-group/Lie-algebra, and mathematicians use [weights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest_weight#Highest_weight), because finite-dimensional irreducible representations are all highest-weight modules.

$\mathfrak{su}(4)$ is a rank 3 Lie algebra of $A$ series, i.e. $A_3$. Denote its roots as $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$, and the corresponding weights $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$. Lowest weight representations $\Lambda_{\omega_1}$ and $\Lambda_{\omega_3}$ are 4 dimensional, and $\Lambda_{\omega_2}$ is 6-dimensional. [Weyl dimensions formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula) gives dimension of the representation $\Lambda_{n_1 \omega_1 + n_2 \omega_2 + n_3 \omega_3}$:
$$
    \dim \Lambda_{n_1 \omega_1 + n_2 \omega_2 + n_3 \omega_3} = \\ \frac{1}{12} \left(n_1+1\right) \left(n_2+1\right) \left(n_3+1\right)\left(n_1+n_2+2\right)  \left(n_2+n_3+2\right) \left(n_1+n_2+n_3+3\right)
$$
$\Lambda_{\omega_2}$ is the only 6-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{su}(4)$. Highest weight modules are stable under the action of the [Weyl group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group) $\mathcal{W}_{\mathfrak{su}(4)} \simeq S_3$, thus they can be constructed as an orbit of the highest weight under the action of Weyl group:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
     \Lambda_{\omega_1} &=& \{ | \omega_1 \rangle,  | \omega_1-\alpha_1 \rangle,  | \omega_1 -\alpha_1 - \alpha_2 \rangle,   | \omega_1 - \alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \rangle \} \\
      \Lambda_{\omega_3} &=& \{ | \omega_3 \rangle,  | \omega_3-\alpha_3 \rangle,  | \omega_3 -\alpha_3 - \alpha_2 \rangle,   | \omega_3 - \alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \rangle \} \\
    \Lambda_{\omega_2} &=& \{ | \omega_2 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 \rangle , \\ &\phantom{=}& \phantom{-} | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - 2 \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle \}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
$\mathcal{W}_{\mathfrak{su}(4)}$ is generated by three refections $\mathcal{W}_{\mathfrak{su}(4)} = \langle w_{\alpha_1}, w_{\alpha_2}, w_{\alpha_3}\rangle$.

Roots $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$ generate sub-algebra $h = \mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{su}(2) \subset \mathfrak{su}(4)$. Fundamental irreducible representations $\Lambda_{\omega_1}$, $\Lambda_{\omega_2}$, $\Lambda_{\omega_3}$ of $\mathfrak{su}(4)$ are reducible under $h$. The decomposition of $\Lambda_\omega$ into irreducible $h$-modules can be obtained by considering the orbit of the highest weight $\omega$ under action of $\mathcal{W}_h = \langle w_{\alpha_1}, w_{\alpha_3} \rangle$:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
     \Lambda_{\omega_1}^{\mathfrak{su}(4)} &=& \Lambda_{\omega_1 \oplus  0}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} \oplus \Lambda_{0 \oplus \omega_3}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} = \{ | \omega_1 \rangle, | \omega_1 - \alpha_1 \rangle \} \oplus \{ | \omega_1 -\alpha_1 - \alpha_2 \rangle,   | \omega_1 - \alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \rangle \} \\
      \Lambda_{\omega_3}^{\mathfrak{su}(4)} &=& \Lambda_{\omega_3 \oplus 0}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} \oplus \Lambda_{0 \oplus \omega_1}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} = \{ | \omega_3 \rangle,  | \omega_3-\alpha_3 \rangle \} \oplus \{ | \omega_3 -\alpha_3 - \alpha_2 \rangle,   | \omega_3 - \alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \rangle  \} \\
     \Lambda_{\omega_2}^{\mathfrak{su}(4)} &=& \Lambda_{0 \oplus 0}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} \oplus  \Lambda_{0 \oplus 0}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} \oplus  \Lambda_{3 \omega}^{\mathfrak{su}(2)} = \{ | \omega_2 \rangle \} \oplus \{ | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - 2 \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle \} \oplus \\ &\phantom{= }& \{  | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 \rangle , | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle \}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The 4-dimensional module decomposes with respect to $\langle w_{\alpha_1}\rangle$ as:
$$
     \{ | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 \rangle \} \oplus \{  | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle \}
$$
and with respect to $\langle w_{\alpha_3} \rangle$ as:
$$
  \{ | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle \} \oplus \{  | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 \rangle, | \omega_2 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 \rangle \}
$$

This analysis tells us how the six-dimensional representation $\Lambda_{\omega_2}$ is constructed. The scalar components correspond to anti-symmetric tensors of each $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and the four-dimensional component corresponds to direct product of fundamental representations. Each of the element of the above vector spaces corresponds to a field of the super Yang-Mills theory.

Now to make the connection to $SO(6)$, you need to know the isomorphism with $SU(4)$, i.e. how Cartan-Weyl roots of $\mathfrak{so}(6)$ relate to those of $\mathfrak{su}(4)$. Then you need to find the isomorphism between $\Lambda_{\omega_2}$ constructed above, and the $6$-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{so}(6)$.

Comment: Physicists who want to write clear papers also use weights :).