# Prove that $\det A = 1$ with $A^T M A = M$ and $M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ -I &0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Prove that $\det A = 1$ with $A^T M A = M$ and 
$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ -I &0 \end{bmatrix}$ ($I$ is the identity matrix of order n).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242091/why-is-the-determinant-of-a-symplectic-matrix-1

Comment: could you please post what have you tried till now???

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik I tried to write the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \\ A_3 & A_4 \end{bmatrix}$, and get two equalities of those four submatrices. But then I got stuck...

Comment: do you know any properties of determinants???

Comment: do you at least see that $det(A)=\pm 1$ ?? (just from the equality $det(AB)=det(A).det(B)$)

Comment: this is obvious, I'm stuck because I got no idea on how to exclude the possibility that $\det A = -1$.

Comment: $\det A = \pm 1$ ..."this is obvious" ... exactly the sort of thing that should be included in the original question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix $A$ that you have described is called a [symplectic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix). The result you are interested in is not trivial, and follows from a series of results. For details, see section 4 of Mackey, Mackey, "[On the Determinant of Symplectic Matrices](http://homepages.wmich.edu/~mackey/detsymp.pdf)".

The short version is this:

1. Show that every $A$ is a product of $\mathbb{G}$-reflectors, i.e., matrices of a form
   $$G = I + \beta u u^T M, \quad \text{for some $\beta \ne 0$, $u \ne 0$}.$$
2. Show that each $\mathbb{G}$-reflector $G$ has a determinant $\det G = +1$.