# Spin group Spin(4,1)

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

i'm interested in the spin group $Spin(4,1)$ wich correspond to the symplectic group $Sp(1,1)$. The only source that I could find about it was wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group). It seems that there is no general definition about what a indefinite symplectic group is.  It would be helpful if someone could provide me a text (or a proof) where I could find how come $Spin(4,1)=Sp(1,1)$. Thanks alot to everyone.

For example Cornwell (Group Theory in Physics Vol II,page 392) says:

$Sp(r,\,s)=\{A\in\textbf{GL}(n;\,\mathbb C): A^T\,J\,A=J\:\:{\rm and}\:\: A^\dagger\,G\,A=G\}$, where $r+s=n/2$ and

$J=\left(
\begin{array}{clc}
0   &&   I_{n\times n}\\
-I_{n\times n}
\end{array}\right),\hspace{.5cm} G=\left(
\begin{array}{clclc}
-I_{r\times r}&&0&&0&&0\\
0&&I_{s\times s}&&0&&0\\
0&&0&&-I_{r\times r}&&0\\
0&&0&&0&&I_{s\times s}
\end{array}
\right)$

And there is another definition tha involves quaternions... so, which one?

Comment: See page 10 of http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~cap/files/wisser.pdf . The associated Lie algebra isomorphism is a real consequence, by the way, of the exceptional isomorphism $B_2 \cong C_2$ of semisimple (complex) Lie algebras, which itself has numerous beautiful consequences.

Comment: At a glance the Lie algebras look to be isomorphic, possibly up to a reversal of the roles of $r, s$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the classification of real semisimple Lie algebras?

Comment: No, i'm not familiar, but please explain in those terms that I would learn this topic.

I hate to be abother, but could you please tell me how could you tell, a glance, this would be isomorphic?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to think of quaternionic matrices as complex ones in the "usual" way?

Comment: The only think I know about quaternions is its relation with rotations in the euclidean space... sorry

Comment: See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations , which shows how to write a quaternion as a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix in such a way that quaternion addition and multiplication are mapped to matrix addition and multiplication. Similarly, we can regard any $n \times n$ quaternionic matrix as a $(2n) \times (2n)$ complex matrix by replacing each quaternionic entry with a $2 \times 2$ minor, and again, this maps the involved operations in the right way. This determines an embedding $M(n, \mathbb{H}) \hookrightarrow M(2n, \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I see... wow, that was very helpful. Thanks a lot. And, a last question, would you know if this groups is isomorphic to any other group?

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. And do you mean, does it have any other faithful matrix representations besides the two already discussed? If so, there's also a perfectly good real representation: You can write a complex number $a + bi$ as a $2 \times 2$ real matrix \begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix} and play the same sort of game as above, which gives a representation of $Sp(p, q)$ as $(4n) \times (4n)$ real matrices.

Comment: Beyond these and the obvious isomorphic groups given by making other natural choices of $J$ and $G$, I don't know of any other common representations for these groups, they don't seem to come up very often in the wild, anyway.

Comment: Yes, trully they don't. I want to define the spinors in the compactificated 3-d euclidean space, and because its conformal group is $SO(4,\,1)$, all it came down to this. Something like twistors at this dimension.

Answer (score 3):

> Proposition A:
> $$SU(p,q;\mathbb{H})~\cong~U(p,q;\mathbb{H})~\cong~Sp(p,q).\tag{1}$$

*Sketched proof:*

1. The indefinite [unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) over the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) is
   $$\begin{align} U(p,q;\mathbb{H})~:=~& \left\{ 
   x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H}) \left| x^{\dagger}\eta x =\eta   \right. \right\},\cr 
    ~=~&\left\{ 
   x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H}) \left| x^{\dagger\eta} x ={\bf 1}_{n \times n}   \right. \right\}, \cr 
   n~=~&p+q,\qquad 
   x^{\dagger\eta}~:=~\eta x^{\dagger}\eta,\cr
   \eta~:=~&{\rm diag}(\underbrace{+1,\ldots,+1}_p,\underbrace{-1,\dots, -1}_q),\cr 
   \eta^2~=~&{\bf 1}_{n \times n}.\end{align} \tag{2}  $$
   Let us mention for completeness that the corresponding Lie algebra
   $$u(p,q;\mathbb{H})~:=~ \left\{ 
   x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H}) \left| x^{\dagger\eta}=- x   \right. \right\} \tag{3} $$
   of $\eta$-anti-Hermitian matrices has real dimension
   $$\dim_{\mathbb{R}}u(p,q;\mathbb{H})
   ~=~4\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+3n~=~n(2n+1).\tag{4} $$
   $U(p,q;\mathbb{H})$ has $p(2p+1)+q(2q+1)$ anti-Hermitian/compact and $4pq$ Hermitian/non-compact generators, respectively.
2. The indefinite unitary group over the complex numbers is
   $$U(2p,2q)~:=~ \left\{ 
   M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C}) \left| M^{\dagger}(\eta\otimes {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2} ) M =\eta\otimes {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}   \right. \right\}. \tag{5}$$
3. The [symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) over the complex numbers is
   $$\begin{align} Sp(2n;\mathbb{C})~:=~& \left\{ 
   M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C}) \left| M^t\Omega M =\Omega  \right. \right\}\cr
   ~\cong~&\left\{ 
   M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C}) \left| M^t(\eta\otimes\omega) M =(\eta\otimes\omega)  \right. \right\}\cr
   ~=:~&Sp(2p,2q;\mathbb{C}), \cr 
     \Omega ~:=~&{\bf 1}_{n \times n}\otimes \omega~=~-\Omega^t, \cr 
   \omega ~:=~&\mathrm{i}\sigma_2~=~-\omega^t , \cr
   \Omega^2~=~&-{\bf 1}_{2n \times 2n}.\end{align}\tag{6}$$
   The proof that we can use $\eta\otimes\omega$ rather than $\Omega$ as symplectic unit follows from index relabelling of rows (and the corresponding index relabelling of columns).
4. The indefinite [symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) is defined as
   $$\begin{align} Sp(p,q)~:=~&U(2p,2q) \cap Sp(2p,2q;\mathbb{C})\cr
   ~=~&\left\{ M\in U(2p,2q) \left|  M^t(\eta\otimes\omega) M =(\eta\otimes\omega)  \right. \right\} \cr
   ~=~&\left\{ M\in U(2p,2q) \left| \overline{M}\Omega  = \Omega M  \right. \right\},   \cr 
   (\eta\otimes {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}) \Omega~=~& \Omega(\eta\otimes {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}).\end{align}\tag{7} $$
5. The condition
   $$\overline{M}\Omega  ~=~ \Omega M \tag{8} $$
   is the condition
   $$ \overline{m}_{ij}\omega ~=~\omega m_{ij}, \qquad
    i,j~\in~\{1,\ldots,n\},\tag{9} $$
   that each of the  $2\times 2$ blocks $m_{ij}$ in
   $$M~=~\begin{pmatrix} m_{11}  &\ldots  & m_{1n} \cr  
   \vdots &\ddots  & \vdots \cr 
   m_{n1}  &\ldots &  m_{nn}\end{pmatrix}~\in~{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C})\tag{10}$$
   can be identified with a quaternion, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/271425/2451). In other words, there is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra isomorphism
   $$ \Phi:~~{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})~~\longrightarrow \left\{ 
   M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C}) \left| \overline{M} \Omega = \Omega M  \right. \right\}.\tag{11} $$
   $\Phi$ is actual a star algebra isomorphism
   $$ \Phi(x^{\dagger})~=~\Phi(x)^{\dagger},  \qquad x~\in~{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H}).\tag{12}$$
6. Conclude the group isomorphism
   $$U(p,q;\mathbb{H})~\stackrel{\Phi_|}{\cong}~Sp(p,q).\tag{13}$$
7. The first isomorphism in Proposition A now follows from the fact that [symplectic matrices has unit determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/242091/11127).

$\Box$

> Proposition B:
>
> 1. $G:=U(2; \mathbb{H})$ is (the double cover of) the [special orthogonal group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) $SO(5).$
> 2. $G:=U(1,1; \mathbb{H})$ is (the double cover of) the [restricted de Sitter group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $SO^+(1,4).$

*Sketched proof:*

1. Since quaternions are non-commutative, [care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_matrix) should be taken when defining
   trace (& determinant). The reduced trace is defined as
   $$\begin{align} {\rm Re~tr} (x)~=~&\frac{1}{2} {\rm tr} (x+x^{\dagger})\cr
   ~=~&\frac{1}{2} {\rm tr} (\Phi(x)), \cr  
   x~\in~&{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}),\end{align}\tag{14} $$
   which is [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29),
   e.g. because
   $$ {\rm Re}(qq^{\prime})~=~{\rm Re}(q^{\prime}q), \qquad q,q^{\prime}~\in~\mathbb{H}.\tag{15} $$
2. There is a bijective isometry from $\mathbb{R}^5$ [or $\mathbb{R}^{1,4}$] to the $\mathbb{R}$-inner product space
   $$\begin{align} V~=~& \left\{ x\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \left|  x^{\dagger\eta}=x~~\wedge~~ {\rm Re~tr} (x)=0 \right. \right\} \cr
   ~=~&\left\{\left. \begin{pmatrix} r & q \cr \pm\bar{q} & -r \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \right| r\in\mathbb{R}~~\wedge~~q\in\mathbb{H}\right\},\end{align}\tag{16}$$
   equipped with the (indefinite) quadratic form
   $$ || x||^2~:=~ \frac{1}{2}{\rm Re~tr} (x^2)~=~r^2 \pm |q|^2  ,  \tag{17}$$
   where $\pm$ corresponds to the two cases in Proposition B.
3. There is a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $\rho:G\times V \to V$ given by conjugation
   $$ \rho(g)x~:=~gxg^{-1}~=~gxg^{\dagger\eta}, \qquad g~\in ~G, \qquad x~\in~ V, \tag{18}$$
   which is length preserving, i.e. $g$ is a (pseudo)orthogonal transformation.
   In other words, there is a Lie group homomorphism
   $\rho: G\rightarrow O(V)$, where
   $$\rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2})~=~{\bf 1}_V.\tag{19}$$
   $\Box$

> Proposition C:
> $$G~:=~SL(2;\mathbb{H})~:=~\Phi^{-1}(SL(4;\mathbb{C})) \tag{20}$$
> is (the double cover of) the special orthogonal group $SO^+(1,5).$

*Sketched proof:*

1. Let
   $$so(4,\mathbb{C})~:=~\left\{ 
   A\in{\rm Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C}) \left| A^t = -A \right. \right\}\tag{21}$$
   denote the set of antisymmetric complex $4\times 4$ matrices,
   endowed with the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian)
   $$\begin{align} {\rm Pf}(A)~=~&\frac{1}{8}\sum_{\mu,\nu,\lambda,\sigma=1}^4\epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}A^{\mu\nu} A^{\lambda\sigma}\cr
   ~=~&A^{12}A^{34} + A^{31}A^{24} + A^{23}A^{14}, \cr 
    \epsilon_{1234}~=~&1.\end{align}\tag{22}$$
2. If we define a "transposed" quaternion as
   $$ q^t~:=~q|_{q^2\to-q^2}~=~-j\bar{q}j, \qquad q~\in~\mathbb{H}, \tag{23}$$
   then
   $$ \Phi(x)^t~=~\Phi(x^t),  \qquad x~\in~{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}). \tag{24}$$
3. Let the set of "antisymmetric" quaternion $2\times 2$ matrices be
   $$\begin{align}so(2;\mathbb{H})
   ~:=~& \left\{ x\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \mid x^t=-x \right\}\cr 
   ~=~&\Phi^{-1}(so(4,\mathbb{C}))~=~jV~=~V\!j,\end{align}\tag{25} $$
   where
   $$\begin{align} V~:=~&u(2;\mathbb{H})~:= \left\{ x\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \mid x^{\dagger}=x \right\} \cr
   ~=~&\left\{\left. \begin{pmatrix} r  & q \cr \bar{q} & s \end{pmatrix} \in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{H}) \right| r,s\in\mathbb{R}, ~q\in\mathbb{H} \right\}\cr
   ~\cong~&\mathbb{R}^{1,5}\end{align}\tag{26} $$
   is the real vector space of Hermitian quaternion $2\times 2$ matrices.
4. Endow $V\!j$ with the indefinite quadratic form
   $$\begin{align} ||xj||^2 ~=~& {\rm Pf}(\Phi(xj))\cr
   ~=~& \frac{1}{2}{\rm Re~tr} (x^2)-\frac{1}{2}{\rm Re~tr} (x)^2\cr
   ~=~&rs \pm |q|^2 .\end{align}\tag{27} $$
5. There is a group action $\rho:G\times V\!j \to V\!j$
   $$ \begin{align} \rho(g)x~:=~&gxg^{\dagger}j~=~gxjg^t, \cr 
   g~\in ~&G, \qquad x~\in~ V, \end{align}\tag{28}$$
   which is length preserving, i.e. $g$ is a (pseudo)orthogonal transformation.
   In other words, there is a Lie group homomorphism
   $\rho: G\rightarrow O(V)$, where
   $$\rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2})~=~{\bf 1}_V.\tag{29}$$
   $\Box$

References:

1. Paul Garrett, [*Sporadic isogenies to orthogonal groups,*](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf) 2015.

Comment: Notes for later: The [complexification](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Complexification_of_a_Lie_algebra) $u(p,q)_{\mathbb{C}}:=u(p,q)\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} \cong gl(n,\mathbb{C})$; $sp(2n,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{C}}:=sp(2n,\mathbb{C})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} \cong sp(2n,\mathbb{C})\oplus sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$. Hence $U(p,q)_{\mathbb{C}} \cong GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $Sp(p,q)_{\mathbb{C}} \cong Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Notes for later: $gl(n,\mathbb{H})_{\mathbb{C}} \cong gl(2n,\mathbb{C})$. Hence $GL(n,\mathbb{H})_{\mathbb{C}} \cong GL(2n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Notes to self: Helgason defines $Sp(n,\mathbb{H}):=\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid x^{\dagger}(j{\bf 1}_{n\times n})x=j{\bf 1}_{n\times n}\}$ $=\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid x^tx={\bf 1}_{n\times n}\}$ $=\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C})\mid M^tM={\bf 1}_{2n\times 2n},~\overline{M}\Omega=\Omega M\}$. $\quad sp(n,\mathbb{H})=\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid x^t=-x\}$ $=\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid x^{\dagger}=jxj\}$ $=\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid (jx)^{\dagger}=jx\}$. $\quad\dim_{\mathbb{R}}sp(n,\mathbb{H})=n(2n\!-\!1)$.

Comment: Signature is not important: $\quad D~:=~{\rm diag}(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_p,\underbrace{i,\dots, i}_q)$. $\quad x^{\prime}=DxD^{-1}$. $\quad Sp(n,\mathbb{H})\cong Sp(p,q;\mathbb{H}):=\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid  x^{\dagger}j\eta x = j\eta\}$.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad sp(2,\mathbb{H})\cong su(2)\oplus sl(2,\mathbb{R})$, where $su(2)$ is spanned by 3 compact/anti-Hermitian ${\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\otimes \omega$, $\omega\otimes\sigma_x$, $\omega\otimes\sigma_z$; while  $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ is spanned by 1 compact/anti-Hermitian $\omega\otimes {\bf 1}_{2\times 2}$ and 2 non-compact/Hermitian $\sigma_z\otimes i\omega$, $\sigma_x\otimes i\omega$.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad GL(n,\mathbb{F}) := \{M\in {\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}) \mid \det(M)\neq 0\}$. $\quad SL(n,\mathbb{F}) := \{M\in {\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}) \mid \det(M)=1\}$. For $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{H}$, the notion of $\det$ is via an [imbedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_matrix#Determinants) to $2n\times 2n$ complex matrices.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad U(n)\subseteq Sp(n,\mathbb{H})$. $\quad Sp(n,\mathbb{H})_{\mathbb{C}}\cong SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$. $\quad O(n,\mathbb{C})$ $=\left\{\left. \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \cr 0 & A^{-1,\dagger} \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C})  \right| A\in O(n,\mathbb{C})\right\}\subseteq Sp(n,\mathbb{H})$.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad U(n)\subseteq SO(2n;\mathbb{R})$. Proof: $\quad\Phi(M)^t\Phi(M)={\bf 1}_{2n\times 2n}$. $\quad O(n,\mathbb{C})\subseteq SO(n,n;\mathbb{R})$. Proof: $\quad\Phi(M)^t({\bf 1}_{n\times n}\otimes\sigma_1)\Phi(M)({\bf 1}_{n\times n}\otimes\sigma_1)={\bf 1}_{2n\times 2n}$. $\quad SO(2,\mathbb{C})=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix} \cos(z)& \sin(z)\cr -\sin(z)&\cos(z) \end{pmatrix}\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})\right| z\in\mathbb{C}\right\}$. $\quad O(2,\mathbb{C})=\quad SO(2,\mathbb{C})\cup\sigma_1SO(2,\mathbb{C})$.