# How to see that $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^3\cong\mathrm{SO}(5)/\mathrm{U}(2)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, twistor-theory

I stumbled on this ismorphism in the context of twistor fibrations. See for example 'Twistors in Mathematics and Physics' by Bailey and Baston, p.58. Can anybody provide a construction of this isomorphism?

Answer (score 3):

Sketched proof:
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{H}^2/\mathbb{C}^{\times}~\cong~\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^3~\stackrel{?}{\cong}~&SO(5)/U(2)\cr 
~\cong~& [SPIN(5)/\mathbb{Z}_2]/\{[U(1)\times SU(2)]/\mathbb{Z}_2\}\cr 
~\cong~& SPIN(5)/[U(1)\times SU(2)]\cr 
~\cong~& U(2,\mathbb{H})/[U(1)\times U(1,\mathbb{H})],\end{align} \tag{1}$$
because
$$\begin{align} SPIN(5)~\cong~& U(2,\mathbb{H}), \cr
U(2)~\cong~& [U(1)\times SU(2)]/\mathbb{Z}_2\cr
SU(2)~\cong~& U(1,\mathbb{H}), \end{align} \tag{2} $$

cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105200/11127) Math.SE post and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169087/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271419/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Removing a $U(1)$ phase, it is enough to prove

> $$ \mathbb{H}^2/\mathbb{R}_+~\stackrel{?}{\cong}~U(2,\mathbb{H})/ U(1,\mathbb{H}). \tag{3}$$

The right-hand side of eq. (3) consists of

$$\begin{align} &U(2,\mathbb{H})\cr
&~\cong~ 
\left\{ \left.\begin{pmatrix} \alpha a & \beta b \cr \beta c & \alpha d \end{pmatrix}\right| a,b,c,d\in U(1,\mathbb{H}), ~\bar{a}b+\bar{c}d=0,~\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+,~  \alpha^2 +\beta^2=1\right\} \end{align}\tag{4}$$
in the numerator, while the left-hand side of eq. (3) consists of
$$ \mathbb{H}^2/\mathbb{R}_+~\cong~\left\{ ( \alpha a , \beta b  )\in \mathbb{H}^2 \mid a,b\in U(1,\mathbb{H}),~\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+,~  \alpha^2 +\beta^2=1\right\}.\tag{5}$$
$\Box$