# A determinant from the real and imaginary parts of a unitary matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, unitary-matrices

Let $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ unitary matrix, $U_1 = \operatorname{Re} U$ (real part of $U$), and $U_2 = \operatorname{Im} U$ (imaginary part of $U$). The construct the $2n \times 2n$ matrix

$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
U_1 & -U_2 \\ U_2 & U_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

One can show that $J$ is an orthogonal matrix (thanks to the comment of [@Salcio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/821280/salcio)): calculate

$$
\begin{align*}
    J^\mathsf{T} J
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        U_1^\mathsf{T} U_1 + U_2^\mathsf{T} U_2
        & -U_1^\mathsf{T} U_2 + U_2^\mathsf{T} U_1 
        \\
        U_1^\mathsf{T} U_2 - U_2^\mathsf{T} U_1 
        & U_1^\mathsf{T} U_1 + U_2^\mathsf{T} U_2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

Since $U$ is unitary, we get

$$
\begin{align*}
    U^\dagger U 
    &= (U_1^\mathsf{T} - iU_2^\mathsf{T}) (U_1 + iU_2)
    \\
    &= (U_1^\mathsf{T} U_1 + U_2^\mathsf{T} U_2)
    + i(U_1^\mathsf{T} U_2 - U_2^\mathsf{T} U_1)
    = 1
\end{align*}
$$

The real and the imaginary parts of this equation gives

$$
U_1^\mathsf{T} U_1 + U_2^\mathsf{T} U_2 = 1, \quad
U_1^\mathsf{T} U_2 - U_2^\mathsf{T} U_1 = 0
$$

Therefore $J^\mathsf{T} J = 1$, and $\det J = \pm 1$. Now the problem is that in my numerical test I always get $\det J = +1$. The code for the test is shown below (in Python, using the unitary matrix generator from [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.unitary_group.html)):

```
import numpy as np
# generator of random unitary matrices
from scipy.stats import unitary_group
# dimension of the unitary matrix
n = 3
u = unitary_group.rvs(n)
u1, u2 = u.real, u.imag
j = np.block([[u1, -u2], [u2, u1]])
print(np.linalg.det(j))
```

How to further prove (or disprove) that $\det J = +1$ (ruling out the possibility $-1$)?

---

*Motivation of the definition of $J$*: consider two complex vectors $z, w \in \mathbb{C}^n$ related by $w = Uz$. Let

$$
\begin{align*}
    z &= z_1 + iz_2 && (z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n) \\
    w &= w_1 + iw_2 && (w_1,w_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n)
\end{align*}
$$

Then the real vectors $z_1,z_2,w_1,w_2$ are related by

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    w_1 \\ w_2
\end{bmatrix} = J \begin{bmatrix}
    z_1 \\ z_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: From Hadamard's inequality you get $|detJ| <=1$. At the same time (still from the Hadamard's inequality, this time its proof or geometric interpretation) equality would imply that rows of $J$ are orthogonal which is ... unlikely.

Comment: Have you tried numerical examples when $n=2$?

Comment: I updated the question now that I can show that $J$ is orthogonal, but still do not know why I always get $\det J = +1$ in numerical tests.

Comment: The map $U\mapsto J$ is a homomorphism $U(n)\to O(2n)$. (You pick a unitary matrix, interpret it as an $\Bbb R$-linear transformation of $\Bbb C^n$ with $\Bbb R$-basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n,ie_1,\cdots, ie_n\}$.) Since $U(n)$ is connected and the homomorphism is continuous, the image must be in the identity component of $O(2n)$, namely $SO(2n)$. Or equivalently, compose $U\mapsto J$ with the homomorphism $\det:O(2n)\to\{\pm1\}$, and apply the same logic with the codomain being discrete. That's why $\det J$ must be $1$.

Comment: @runway44 Maybe you can make your comment an answer. But somehow I believe that there must exist a more elementary proof...

Comment: Your block matrix is a special case of symplectic matrix. Every symplectic matrix (over any field) has determinant $1$. You may see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/242091) for some elementary proofs.