# $Spin(6,2) = SU(2, 2, \mathbb{H})$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spin-geometry

On Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Indefinite_signature, it says $Spin(6,2) = SU(2, 2, \mathbb{H})$. But I cannot find any reference. Does anyone know one, or any other references which explains what this spin group is? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check the references $1.,2.,3.,4.$ of the wikipedia article?

Comment: Yes. I think they are all theories. Plus I saw another reference request question on here which asked the reference for Spin(4,1) <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105200/spin-group-spin4-1>

Comment: Don't think so: the reference it gives: Paul Garrett, Sporadic isogenies to orthogonal groups, 2015, does not cover this example. Plus I am not even sure about the authenticity of this statement on wikipedia

Comment: I have seen it before (perhaps in Helgason's book). We also have $Spin(6)=SU(4)$ and $Spin(4,2)≃SU(2,2)$. Now take $\Bbb H=\Bbb R^4$. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin+group).

Comment: Or chapter $6$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjD_7O4yf_1AhUsPewKHWOnAik4ChAWegQIEhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni-hamburg.de%2Fhome%2Fschulte-hengesbach%2Fdiploma.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3UWJQWTcSLCt6H4TEWH6io).

Comment: Is there an elementary description of what this ${\rm SU}(2,2,\Bbb H)$ thing is? My understanding is that the $4\times4$ quaternionic matrices whose transformations of $\Bbb H^4$ preserve the form $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2−|x_3|^2−|x_4|^2$ make up a $36$-dimensional group which I would call $\rm Sp(2,2)$, but $\rm Spin(6,2)$ is $28$-dimensional so it can't be that. I am particularly interested in if we can see $\rm Spin(5,2)$ or $\rm Spin(6,1)$ in this classical group, or see how $AB$ embeds in it for $A$, $B$ classical groups corresponding to ${\rm Spin}(p,q)$, ${\rm Spin}(r,s)$ and $(p+q,r+s)=(6,2)$.

Comment: @runway44 Yes now I agree Spin$(6,2)$ is not SU$(2,2,\mathbb{H})$. In fact we don't have a faithful representation of Spin$(6,2)$: all I know is that Spin(2,6) embeds inside SK$(4, \mathbb{H}) \times$ SK$(4,\mathbb{H})$ (SK$(4,\mathbb{H})$ = SO*$(8)$). See Harvey's book "Spinors and Calibrations".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case that shows what a great thing the Tits index a.k.a. [Satake diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satake_diagram) is. Here is Remark 4.5.20.ii from [my thesis](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/algebres-de-lie-semi-simples-et-leur-classification-sur-les-corps-p-adiques):

[image]

(The reference Jac6 is *Lie Algebras* by Nathan Jacobson. Interscience Tracts in Pure and Applied Mathematics, Number 10. John Wiley and Son, Inc. New York, 1962.)

The algebra belonging to the thing on the right would almost always be written $\mathfrak{so}(6,2)$, and then of course its corresponding simply connected group is $Spin(6,2)$. The thing on the left, unfortunately, seems to not have a standard name (neither the Lie algebra nor its corresponding simply connected group), so in every source we have to check the nomenclature. In [Schulte-Hengesbach's diploma thesis](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schulte-hengesbach/diploma.pdf) mentioned by Dietrich Burde in a comment, the Lie algebra is called $\mathfrak{sp}(2, \mathbb H)$; in [Onishchik/Vinberg's tables](https://books.google.de/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&pg=PA230&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false), the Lie algebra is called $\mathfrak{u}^*_{4}(\mathbb H)$; apparently your source calls the corresponding simply connected group $SU(2,2, \mathbb H)$.

Finally, here is how Tits describes both forms in his article in the [Boulder Proceedings](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Epanchish/ETE%20LAMA%202018-AP/Borel_Algebraic%20Groups%20and%20Discontinuous%20Subgroups.pdf) (p.56/57). He talks about groups. The form on the left is, in Tits' notation, $^1D^{(2)}_{4,2}$ (i.e. $n=4, d=2, r=2$), and he would call it $SU_4(\mathbb H, h)$ for a certain $h$ as described below (I think Jacobson's and my description above matches rather his "equivalent description for $d \ge 2$", but I'm not entirely sure about that). The form on the right is $^1D^{(1)}_{4,2}$ (i.e. $n=4, d=1, r=2$).

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1. Am I correct in saying this is an isomorphism of two of the real forms of $Spin(8)$ (or $\mathfrak{so}(8)$) due to triality? Is $SU(2,2,\mathbb{H})$ the same thing that I often see called $SO^*(8)$?

Comment: @Callum: First question, yes (certainly). Second question, possibly ...

Comment: @Callum: I think so for the second question: if you see Helgason P.527 for an alternative definition of $SO^*(8)$, it looks very much like the definition of $SU(2,2,\mathbb{H})$ after identifying $\mathbb{H}$ as 2-by-2 matrices over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Now I would disagree to myself more than half a year ago. They are totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

1. On one hand, the Lie group $SO^+(6,2;\mathbb{R})$ has 16 compact and 12 non-compact dimensions, in total 28 real dimensions.

   On the other hand, the most natural definition of $SU(2,2;\mathbb{H})$ would be the set of $4\times 4$ quaternionic matrices that are unitary wrt. a split metric of signature (2,2), and has unit [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_matrix#Determinants). However this Lie group has 20 compact and 16 non-compact dimensions, in total 36 real dimensions, cf. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021535/11127). So [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Indefinite_signature) [August 2023] must either be wrong or use another definition. Here we will instead consider the Lie group $U^{\ast}(4,\mathbb{H})$ to be defined in eq. (1) below.
2. Let us define the Lie group [1] that is invariant wrt. an anti-Hermitian metric
   $$\begin{align} U^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})~:=~&\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times
   n}(\mathbb{H})\mid x^{\dagger}(j{\bf 1}_{n\times n})x=j{\bf 1}_{n\times
   n}\}\cr
   ~\cong~&\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C})\mid M^{\dagger}\Omega M=\Omega,~\overline{M}\Omega=\Omega M\}, \cr
   ~\cong~&\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C})\mid M^tM={\bf 1}_{2n\times
   2n},~\overline{M}\Omega=\Omega M\}, \cr
     \Omega ~:=~&{\bf 1}_{n \times n}\otimes \omega~=~-\Omega^t, \cr
   \omega ~:=~&\mathrm{i}\sigma_2~=~-\omega^t , \cr
   \Omega^2~=~&-{\bf 1}_{2n \times 2n},\end{align}\tag{1}$$
   cf. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021535/11127).
3. The condition
   $$\overline{M}\Omega  ~=~ \Omega M \tag{2} $$
   is the condition
   $$ \overline{m}_{ij}\omega ~=~\omega m_{ij}, \qquad
    i,j~\in~\{1,\ldots,n\},\tag{3} $$
   that each of the  $2\times 2$ blocks $m_{ij}$ in
   $$M~=~\begin{pmatrix} m_{11}  &\ldots  & m_{1n} \cr
   \vdots &\ddots  & \vdots \cr
   m_{n1}  &\ldots &  m_{nn}\end{pmatrix}~\in~{\rm Mat}_{2n\times
   2n}(\mathbb{C})\tag{4}$$
   can be identified with a quaternion, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer
   [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/271425/2451).
4. *Proposition:* $\det(M)=1$ for a matrix $M$ in eq. (1). *Proof:* To be filled later. $\Box$
   Corollary:
   $$ SU^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})~=~U^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H}), \tag{5}$$
   where $S$=special=unit determinant.
5. It follows that the complexification is the complex special orthogonal group
   $$ U^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})_{\mathbb{C}}~\cong~\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times
   2n}(\mathbb{C})\mid
   M^tM={\bf 1}_{2n\times 2n},~\det(M)=1\}~=~SO(2n,\mathbb{C}).\tag{6}$$
6. By choosing elements of the form $x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times
   n}(\mathbb{R}\oplus j\mathbb{R})$ in eq. (1), we see that that
   $$U(n)~\subseteq~ U^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H}) \tag{7} $$
   is a compact subgroup of $U^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})$. In fact we shall see below that $U(n)$ is a [maximal compact subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) of $U^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})$.
7. The corresponding Lie algebra is
   $$\begin{align}u^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})
   ~=~&\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid x^{\dagger}=jxj\} \cr
   ~=~&\{x\in{\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{H})\mid (jx)^{\dagger}=jx\}\cr
   ~\cong~&\{m\in{\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C})\mid m^t =-m,~m^{\dagger}=\Omega m\Omega\}\cr
   ~=~&\left\{\left. m=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr c & d \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{C}) \right| a^t=-a, b^{\dagger}=b, c= -b^t, d=-a^{\dagger} \right\}.
   \end{align}\tag{8} $$
   It has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n^2$ [real antisymmetric =
   anti-Hermitian] compact and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=n(n-1)$
   [imaginary antisymmetric = Hermitian] non-compact generators, respectively. In total,
   $$ \dim_{\mathbb{R}}u^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})~=~n(2n\!-\!1).\tag{9}$$
8. *Central question:*

   > *Could
   > $$u^{\ast}(n,\mathbb{H})~\stackrel{?}{\cong}~so(p,q;\mathbb{R})\tag{10}$$
   > be isomorphic to an indefinite orthogonal Lie algebra?*

   Well, $so(p,q;\mathbb{R})$ has $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}+\frac{q(q-1)}{2}$ [real antisymmetric = anti-Hermitian] compact and $pq$ [real symmetric = Hermitian] non-compact generators,  respectively. In total
   $$ \dim_{\mathbb{R}}so(p,q;\mathbb{R})~=~\frac{(p+q)(p+q-1)}{2}.\tag{11}$$
   Comparing eqs. (9) & (11) yields $2n=p+q$. Together with $pq=n(n-1)$ this leads to
   $$ \left. \begin{array}{lcr} p&=& n\pm r \cr
     q&=& n\mp r \end{array}\right\} \quad\text{where} \quad
   r~:=~\sqrt{n}~\in~\mathbb{N}_0. \tag{12} $$
   In other words, $n=r^2$ should be a square.

   > Could the compact subalgebras
   > $$u(n)~\cong~ su(n)\oplus u(1)
   > ~\stackrel{?}{\cong}~so(p,\mathbb{R})\oplus so(q,\mathbb{R})\tag{13}$$
   > be isomorphic?

   Well, then clearly $p\leq 2 \vee q\leq 2 $. Comparing with eq. (11) we see that $n\leq 4$. It follows that there are at most 2 examples:
   $$(n,p,q)~=~(1,2,0) \qquad\text{and} \qquad(n,p,q)~=~(4,6,2)\tag{14}$$
   up to a trivial $p\leftrightarrow q$ symmetry.
9. *First example:*
   $$\begin{align}U^{\ast}(1,\mathbb{H})
   ~\cong~&\left\{\left. M=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \cr -\bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha} \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \right| M^t=M^{-1}\right\}\cr
   ~=~&\left\{\left. M=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \cr -\bar{\beta} &
   \bar{\alpha} \end{pmatrix}\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \right| |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1\right\}\cr
   ~=~&SO(2,\mathbb{R}).
   \end{align}\tag{15} $$
10. *Second and main example:*
    $$U^{\ast}(4,\mathbb{H})~\cong~Spin^+(6,2;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}_2~\cong~SO^+(6,2;\mathbb{R}).\tag{16}$$
    Both Lie groups have 16 compact and 12 non-compact dimensions, in total 28 real dimensions. The compact subgroups are locally isomorphic
    $$ U(4)~\cong~[SU(4)\times U(1)]/\mathbb{Z}_4 ~\cong~ [Spin(6,\mathbb{R})\times SO(2,\mathbb{R})]/\mathbb{Z}_4, \tag{17}$$
    cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193546/11127) Math.SE post and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169087/2451) Phys.SE post. The corresponding Lie algebras satisfy
    $$\begin{align} u^{\ast}(4,\mathbb{H})~\cong~&u(4)\oplus \mathfrak{p}~\cong~so(6,2;\mathbb{R}),\cr
    so(4,\mathbb{R})\oplus j~{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4})
    ~\cong~&u(4)~\cong~su(4)\oplus j~u(1)
    ~\cong~so(6,\mathbb{R})\oplus j~so(2,\mathbb{R}),\cr
    \mathfrak{p}~\cong~&i~so(4,\mathbb{R})\oplus k~so(4,\mathbb{R})
    ~\cong~\underline{\bf 6}\otimes \underline{\bf 2},\cr 
     \mathbb{Z}_4~\cong~&\{\pm 1,\pm j\},\cr 
    so(4,\mathbb{R})~\cong~&\bigwedge\!{}^2 \underline{\bf 4}~\cong~\underline{\bf 6}, \qquad
    so(6,\mathbb{R})~\cong~\bigwedge\!{}^2 so(4,\mathbb{R}), \cr
    [u(4),\mathfrak{p}]~\subseteq~&\mathfrak{p},\qquad 
    [\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{p}]~\subseteq~u(4),\cr
    [so(4,\mathbb{R}),{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4})]~\subseteq~&{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4}),\qquad \{so(4,\mathbb{R}),{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4})\}_+~\subseteq~{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4}),\cr
    [{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4}),{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4})]~\subseteq~&so(4,\mathbb{R}),\qquad \{so(4,\mathbb{R}),so(4,\mathbb{R})\}_+~\subseteq~{\rm Sym}^2(\underline{\bf 4}).
    \end{align} \tag{18} $$

References:

1. W. Fulton & J. Harris, *Representation theory,* 1991; p. 433.

Comment: References for later: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9910110 https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2688 https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2021 https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697 https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7248 https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08257